# How can I install vimdiff on Windows after installing git bash?

Tags: git, git-bash, vimdiff

I usually use vimdiff when I want to see diff between two points in git. However, I can't find vimdiff in 'git bash' environment on Windows. Therefore, If anybody know how to install or use vimdiff in git bash console, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can launch `vim` in `bash` on Windows, you should be able to launch it in diff mode with `vim -d`. You could then just alias it to `vimdiff` if it's more comfortable.

As you've tagged this with `git`, I'll recommend Tim Pope's [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) git plugin for Vim. With it I do most git work, including diffing without ever leaving Vim. I do this on Windows 7 at work to keep me out of git bash as much as possible, as git bash is very simple and out-of-date (many of the included programs, such as `grep` are versions from c. 2000).